# Couchbase : Error: cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-16.04, couchbase

I am trying to use couchbase server community edition for ubuntu 16.04 for my project via node.js sdk.

But when trying to access my URLs. I am getting this error again and again.

My `app.js` file content is

```
var express = require('express');
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");
var bucket = cluster.openBucket("travel-sample");

bucket.operationTimeout = 120 * 1000; //increase timeout to resolve the issue of cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.get("/person/:id", function (req, res) {
    bucket.get(req.params.id, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).send(error);
        }

        return res.status(200).send(result);
    });

});

app.get("/person/:id", function (req, res) {
    var person = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
    };

    bucket.post(req.params.id, person, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).send(error);
        }

        return res.status(200).send(result);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server is running on port 3000");
});
```

When trying to hit this url via postman http://localhost:3000/person/pulkitarun

It gives error -

```
Error: cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket
    at Bucket._maybeInvoke (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/couchbase/lib/bucket.js:1216:11)
    at Bucket.get (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/couchbase/lib/bucket.js:1360:8)
    at /var/www/html/couchserver/node/app.js:18:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/var/www/html/couchserver/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
```

Please do help.